Residing house, j-channel vs receiving channel questions
I am planning to reside my house with alside ascend board and batten. I am planning to add a layer of polyiso. My windows are old and have wooden brickmolds that are going to remain (no nailing fin.)

My first question: around windows, I am planning to use one of the casings pictured. I assume I have to use the j-channel style? Would I need to have z flashing between the brickmolds and casing? Is there anyway to use the recieving channel style instead (it might allow square miters instead of 45's)
Secondly: I'd really like a skirt board with water table. It'd require j-channel for the bottom of the siding. Is there anyway to instead use the j channel casing mentioned above as the skirt board? I would guess no as the water can't drain, but wanted to see if I am missing something.
